# Statistical method to show a cycling pattern

Tags: time-series, correlation, circular-statistics

let's say I have multiple time-series $A_i(x)$ and $B_i(x)$. Here, $i$ stands for a person (person 1, person 2, person 3, ..., person $i$, ..). Is there a method to show that the fluctuations in $A$ is caused by the fluctuation in $B$? Note that both time-series $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ are periodic, and not necessarily in a synchronous pattern (ie, $A$ might go up, while $B$ is going down). I'm interested if they are moving in the same or in the opposite direction. I know we could use a simple correlation here (to see if they move in the same direction, but not if they are out of sync?).

Thanks,

Comment: To me it seems as if you answer your own question: for each point in time x compute $\alpha_i(x)=A_i(x+1)-A(x)$ and analogously $\beta_i(x)=B_i(x+1)-B(x)$ and then you take the correlation between these two sets... you could also more generally ask: can I predict the movement of A given the one of B (with a possibly more complicated model than just a linear one), I.e. you let your favorite ML algorithm (GLM/GB/SVR/RF/NN/...) run with $\alpha_i(x)$ as target and $\beta_i(x)$ as single explanatory feature...

Comment: If they are out of sync, then what would be the meaning of "same direction"?  By definition, "out of sync" means sometimes they are moving together and sometimes oppositely.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you have a within subjects design, so repeated measures for participants over time. 
Then, depending on how your data is arranged, there are different [analysis types](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/repeated-measures-approaches/).

You could use B and time as independent and  A as dependent variable, since you are interested in predicting A with B. You can then determine whether it's B or time that provokes changes in A

Cheers